# Swift: Cannot assign value of type 'int' to type 'string'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I have four textfields. One is full bath, another is three-quarter baths, another is half baths, and the last is quarter baths. But after I converted to int, I still get the error of "cannot convert value of type int'. Here is the code.

```
HomeSingleton.sharedInstance3.HomeNumberOfFullBathstext = Int(Double(FullBaths.text!)! * 1.0) + Int(Double(Three_FourthsBaths.text!)! * 0.75) + Int(Double(One_HalfBaths.text!)! * 0.5) + Int(Double(One_fourthBaths.text!)! * 0.25)
```

Comment: `HomeNumberOfFullBathstext` is a string, assign it a string not an int.

Comment: @john Assign that entire value to a integer variable and get your output then assign to yourHomeSingleton.sharedInstance3.HomeNumberOfFullBathstext = String(your variable)

Comment: its a string because HomeNumberOfFullBathstext is a string in a singleton and at the end I will call it again and assign that text to a uilabel

Comment: @ TusharSharma can you show me how to do that

Comment: Var a: Int = Int(Double(FullBaths.text!)! * 1.0) + Int(Double(Three_FourthsBaths.text!)! * 0.75) + Int(Double(One_HalfBaths.text!)! * 0.5) + Int(Double(One_fourthBaths.text!)! * 0.25)
AFTER THAT -: HomeSingleton.sharedInstance3. HomeNumberOfFullBathstext = String(a) . Not sure it would work haven't tested.

Comment: @john First try what sahil recommend.

Comment: it only returns whole numbers, and I'm trying to return decimals. What might be the issue in sahils answer

Comment: You type casted to int how will you get decimal values?

Comment: what would I cast it as to get decimals

Comment: @john Type cast as floating point value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error message is showing everything. You need to assign string value to 
`HomeNumberOfFullBathstext`

```
HomeSingleton.sharedInstance3.HomeNumberOfFullBathstext = String(Int(Double(FullBaths.text!)! * 1.0) + Int(Double(Three_FourthsBaths.text!)! * 0.75) + Int(Double(One_HalfBaths.text!)! * 0.5) + Int(Double(One_fourthBaths.text!)! * 0.25))
```

Comment: what's the probelm?

Comment: HomeNumberOfFullBathstext only shows the text of fullbaths.text and not everything added together

Comment: it only returns whole numbers, and I'm trying to return decimals. What might be the issue

Comment: it rounds down and I don't know why

Comment: so if 0.5 is the answer. HomeNumberOfFullBathstext will print "0"

Comment: You would. because you are casting it to int. Agree with @tushar

Comment: what should I cast it as to get decimals then

Comment: Try this
String((Double(FullBaths.text!)! * 1.0) + (Double(Three_FourthsBaths.text!)! * 0.75) + (Double(One_HalfBaths.text!)! * 0.5) + (Double(One_fourthBaths.text!)! * 0.25))

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using:

```
HomeSingleton.sharedInstance3.HomeNumberOfFullBathstext = String(Int(Double(FullBaths.text!)! * 1.0) + Int(Double(Three_FourthsBaths.text!)! * 0.75) + Int(Double(One_HalfBaths.text!)! * 0.5) + Int(Double(One_fourthBaths.text!)! * 0.25))
```